# Regular expressions (RegEx) and dplyr::filter()

Tags: regex, r, dplyr

I have a simple data frame that looks like this:

```
x <- c("aa", "aa", "aa", "bb", "cc", "cc", "cc")
y <- c(101, 102, 113, 201, 202, 344, 407)
df = data.frame(x, y)    

    x   y
1   aa  101
2   aa  102
3   aa  113
4   bb  201
5   cc  202
6   cc  344
7   cc  407
```

I would like to use a dplyr::filter() and a RegEx to filter out all the `y` observations that start with the number `1`

I'm imagining that the code will look something like this:

```
df %>%
  filter(y != grep("^1"))
```

But I am getting an `Error in grep("^1") : argument "x" is missing, with no default`

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You need to double check the documentations for `grepl` and `filter`.

For `grep`/`grepl` you have to also supply the vector that you want to check in (y in this case) and `filter` takes a logical vector (i.e. you need to use `grepl`). If you want to supply an index vector (from `grep`) you can use `slice` instead.

```
df %>% filter(!grepl("^1", y))
```

Or with an index derived from `grep`:

```
df %>% slice(grep("^1", y, invert = TRUE))
```

But you can also just use `substr` because you are only interested in the first character:

```
df %>% filter(substr(y, 1, 1) != 1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I erroneously assumed that regex would recognize which vector I wanted from the left side of the ==.

Answer (score 35):

With a combination of `dplyr`and `stringr` (to stay within the tidyverse), you could do :

```
df %>% filter(!str_detect(y, "^1"))
```

This works because `str_detect` returns a logical vector.

Comment: `str_detect` also has a `negate` argument, so you could use `str_detect(y, "^1", negate=T)` instead of `!str_detect(y, "^1")`