# gsub regex to work for both words boundaries and punctuation

Tags: r, regex

I'm trying to search in sentences for both words (case insensitive) and punctuation symbols.
The below function works well for words, but requires `\\` to work for dots for example ; and thus it leads to unwanted behavior - see below:

```
fun <- function(text, search) {
  gsub(paste0("\\b(", search, ")\\b"), paste0("<mark>", '\\1', "</mark>"),
       text, ignore.case = T)
}
> fun("this is a test.", ".")
[1] "this<mark> </mark>is<mark> </mark><mark>a</mark><mark> </mark>test<mark>.</mark>"

> fun("(this is a test)", ")")
[1] "(this is a test<mark></mark>"
```

Expecting :

```
> fun("this is a test.", ".")
[1] "this is a test<mark>.</mark>"

> fun("(this is a test)", ")")
[1] "(this is a test<mark>)</mark>"
```

What is the best way - regular expression ? - to search for words as well as punctuation symbols in a string ?

Comment: why are you not wanting to escape `.` and `)` to get it to work?

Comment: Mmh, I could make some if else statements, but it doesn't seem to work as wanted either : eg. ```fun <- function(text, search) {
  if (search=="."){
    search<- "\\."
  }
  gsub(paste0("\\b(", search, ")\\b"), paste0("<mark>", '\\1', "</mark>"),
       text, ignore.case = T)
}
fun("this is a test. Yes, it is.", ".")``` results to ```[1] "this is a test. Yes, it is<mark>.</mark>"``` and miss the first dot.

Comment: just run `fun(yourtext, '\\.')` No need of `ifelse`

Comment: I would like it to be user friendly, i.e. typing a word marks the word, typing a ponctuation marks the ponctuation. And of course such that typing a ponctuation doesn't break all marks, as it is the case in the examples shown in my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need

- [Escape special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56683740/3832970)
- [Dynamic adaptive word boundaries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45145800/3832970)
- Since the dynamic adaptive word boundaries are lookarounds, you need to pass `perl=TRUE` to `gsub`.

See the [R code](https://ideone.com/YxY4SS):

```r
## Escaping function
regex.escape <- function(string) {
  gsub("([][{}()+*^$|\\\\?.])", "\\\\\\1", string)
}
fun <- function(text, search) {
  gsub(paste0("(?!\\B\\w)(", regex.escape(search), ")(?<!\\w\\B)"), "<mark>\\1</mark>",
       text, ignore.case = TRUE, perl=TRUE)
}
fun("this is a test.", ".")
# [1] "this is a test<mark>.</mark>"

fun("(this is a test)", ")")
# [1] "(this is a test<mark>)</mark>"
```

Comment: FYI: If you want to learn more about word boundaries, please consider seeing my YT video on [Dynamic adaptive word boundaries](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ngbxagE2b68) on YouTube